# How to use private quay.io images with fleet and CoreOS

Tags: docker-registry, coreos, fleet

I've been trying to deploy containers with `fleet` on a CoreOS cluster. However, some of the docker images are privately stored on `quay.io` requiring a login.

Now I could add a `docker login` as a precondition to every relevant unit file, but that doesn't seem right. I'm sure there must be a way to store the respective registry credentials somewhere docker can find it when trying to download the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful with quay images, many of them are known to still be vulnerable to the heartbleed vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a Quay "robot account", which is a separate set of credentials than your regular account. This is helpful for two reasons:

1. they can be revoked if needed
2. can be limited to a subset of your repositories

When you make a new robot account, if you click "view credentials", you will get the credentials pre-formatted for common use-cases, such as Docker and Kubernetes.

[image: Quay.io Pre-formatted Docker config]

In this case, you want "Docker Configuration", which is placed at `~/.docker/config.json` on the server(s). Docker will automatically use this to authenticate with Quay.io.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I know about creating the credentials. My question related to where I should add that in a CoreOS instance where the docker images are loaded through systemd. There is an /etc/docker directory. Would that be the right place for it and would that also be `config.json`?